# Can I use AFCI/GFCI outdoors

Tags: electrical, gfci, outdoor, afci

I am getting ready to install a 20 amp breaker powering my outdoor lights, outlets, and some shed outlets.

I am most likely going to just have the breaker be a GFCI breaker to have the entire outdoor line GFCI protected.

I have a bunch of 20 amp GFCI/AFCI combined breakers and was curious if AFCI could be used outdoors?

I know it's not required, and to my understanding there is no real harm (outside of potential nuisance tripping).

My question is: Does anyone see any harm with running a duel GFCI/AFCI breaker for outdoor use? Is there a strong opinion AGAINST doing that?

Thanks guys

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can always use a higher level of protection than is required by code so the answer is yes you can.

With the above statement I would caution you that there are distance issues and if you plan on any motor loads I would not use a combination breaker due to tripping issues, but yes it would be code compliant to use what you have you can always change to a GFCI only breakers IF there are issues.

Comment: Well no need for an answer from me. +1